# OpenAI API error: "InvalidRequestError: Resource not found"

Tags: python, openai-api, gpt-3, fine-tuning

I've been trying to upload a JSON file that I will use for fine-tuning my GPT-3 model.
I get an error when trying to upload it.

```
openai.File.create(file=open("training_data.jsonl"), purpose="fine-tune")
```

When I run the command above, I get the following error:

`InvalidRequestError: Resource not found`

Answer (score 1):

#### In general

The `InvalidRequestError: Resource not found` error in general means that you did something wrong in your API request. As stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/python-library-error-types):

| TYPE | OVERVIEW |
| --- | --- |
| InvalidRequestError | **Cause:** Your request was malformed or missing some required parameters, such as a token or an input. **Solution:** The error message should advise you on the specific error made. Check the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/) for the specific API method you are calling and make sure you are sending valid and complete parameters. You may also need to check the encoding, format, or size of your request data. |

The solution depends on the OpenAI API endpoint you want to use. Check the documentation and be careful to make your API request correctly. See the documentation links for the relevant API endpoint you're using:

- [Chat](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat)
- [Completions](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/completions)
- [Audio](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/audio)
- [Images](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/images)
- [Embeddings](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/embeddings)
- [Fine-tuning](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/fine-tuning)
- [Files](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/files)
- [Models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/models)
- [Moderations](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/moderations)

#### Your case

In your case (i.e., Fine-tuning API endpoint), change this...

```
openai.File.create
```

...to this.

```
openai.FineTuningJob.create
```

Also, the `training_file` and `model` parameters are required. See the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/fine-tuning/create?lang=python).

[image: Screenshot]

Try the following:

**test.py**

```
import os
import openai

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

openai.FineTuningJob.create(training_file="file-abc123", model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
```